# ScheduledTimer selector. Objective-c or Swift?

Tags: swift, timer

I am in Xcode 10.3. I try to use the provided `Timer.scheduledTimer`. When it comes to the `selector`, Xcode suggests that I should use `@objc func`. Is there a better way to do that? perhaps with Swift?

```
func startTimer() {
    countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer( timeInterval: 1, 
                                           target: self, 
                                           selector: #selector(updateTime), 
                                           userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateTime() {

    //do something

}
```

(Here explains very well what is a selector: [Timer, #selector explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386782/timer-selector-explanation)
My question is if it is possible now (August 2019) to do that in a better way

Here it explains how to use Timer:
[How can I use Timer (formerly NSTimer) in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007518/how-can-i-use-timer-formerly-nstimer-in-swift) But this question is older than 5 years. If I understand, In that moment #selector(updateTime) was the best solution. My question is if now, August 2019, there is a new simpler way without @objc )

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Timer`. Use the `scheduledTimer` that takes a block instead of a target/selector. BTW - your code and question are about Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40183997/1630618

Comment: The link I gave you in the above comment shows how to use a block and trailing closure syntax to do it the more modern Swifty way.  Even though the question is old, that answer is newer.